# Why does Safari no longer save flash game progress?

Tags: macos, safari, games, adobe-flash

I don't play flash games a lot. In fact, I try to avoid flash whenever possible; I just don't like the thing. However, there are a few games I like to play in my free time, like [Amorphous+](http://www.kongregate.com/games/innocuousGames/amorphous).

Lately (I can't tell you which OS it started happening on, but it happens on Sierra and it didn't happen, back when I was using Snow Leopard), whenever I restart my computer all progress made in those games disappears.

I understand these games save your progress by storing information somewhere on the computer's hard drive. If I right-click on the flash game, I get a contextual menu which includes the options "Settings" and "Global settings":

- If I select "Settings" and then go to the "Local storage" tab, the option to allow the website that hosts the flash game to save files to my computer is selected.
- If I select "Global settings" and then go to the "Storage" tab, the selected option is the one that says "Allow sites to save information on this computer".

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution!

Go to Safari->Preferences->Privacy. For cookies and website data, check "Always allow". Refresh the page and the games save correctly. But you need to risk your privacy doing so.

Edit: It could be Kongregate changing locations of Flash game file recently causing this issue.

Edit 2: I think I found the cause of the issue. I have compared the source code of some webpages on Kongregate. On the pages where the games do not save correctly (such as Anti-Idle: The Game and Amorphous+), there is a string "konggames" in the source code. In the previous states as on Web Archive, there is no such string in the source code. To show that this is indeed the cause and not just the same string appearing everywhere on Kongregate, I checked the game Solarmax 2 and found that the game saves correctly and of now, and there is no string "konggames" in the source code.

This means that Kongregate has recently changed the host of some games to this "konggames" thing. By choosing "allow cookies from websites I visit"  or stronger settings in the preference, you effectively caused Safari and Flash unable to load save correctly because you have not visited the site "konggames".

Comment: Thanks for your reply, edm. I selected "always allow", loaded Amorphous+ on Kongregate, got the easiest achievement and checked website data. Indeed, konggames.com was now in that list. I then switched back to "allow only from sites I visit", restarted Safari and loaded Amorphous+ again. The achievement was gone. Apparently your solution doesn't work for me. :(

Comment: @Rain No, I did not say that I fixed the problem by switching to "allow all cookies" and then back to "allow only from sites I visit". From my experiment, I have to keep "allow all cookies" checked every time I visit Kongregate.

Comment: I know you said that, but it seems odd given that setting it to "always allow" once is enough to make konggames.com appear in my list of websites I have allowed cookies from. Since it is now a "site I visit", I figure Safari should always allow cookies from that site in the future, yet it doesn't.

Comment: @Rain By "visiting konggames.com", you need to visit it literally, typing the link "konggames.com" and press enter, not just storing its cookies. I would not do that though, because I am sure what kind of site it is.

Comment: What do you mean? What kind of site is it?

Comment: @Rain uh? I meant to type "unsure". Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Safari can't do anything about Flash being terrible. Flash is its own environment, (almost) completely separate from the rest of the website. If Flash is messing something up, it's likely that Safari has little to nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well, OK, but do you know why Flash could have stopped saving my data?

Comment: @Rain Flash receives updates itself. Something may well have broke in an update.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard I met the same problem too, that Safari cannot save or load in a Flash game. Flash does not update itself as I turned it off. Your explanation is wrong because this issue suddenly happens a few days ago while I did not update Flash between the time that Safari saves correctly and Safari does not save. Moreover, my Mac uses the same Flash for all browsers. That "Flash is terrible itself" does not explain why Flash games are saving correctly in Firefox on the same Mac.

Comment: @edm doesn’t change the fact that Safari has almost nothing to do with it.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard More fact is that this issue only happens to Safari but not Firefox. From a user's viewpoint, this is completely Safari's problem.

Comment: @edm users are not always correct, sorry to tell you. Flash has bugs, always has, and the game itself may need to be updated. None of those are Safari’s problem. Flash is a stability and security risk. You should probably avoid it.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I've been getting from Apple a lot. It doesn't really answer the question. The question is not whether it's Safari's fault or Flash's fault. Neither is it whether Flash poses risks for the user. The question is why Flash isn't saving progress when edm and I (and presumably many other users) use Safari. I don't care whose fault it is; I want to know why it happens so I may prevent it in the future.

Comment: Not saying @WilliamTFroggard is associated with Apple; his answer just reminded me of the kinds of answers I've gotten from Apple lately.

Comment: @Rain I don’t work for Apple. The point is, there isn’t always anything you can do about this sort of thing. If you can track down the game’s developer, he may be able to help you. If you can contact a Flash developer, they may be able to help you. If you can track down a Safari developer, they’d most likely tell you what I’m telling you now: not their problem. Either contact Adobe, or whoever wrote the game. This is one of the reasons the tech industry hates Flash so much. It just adds unnecessary complexity to everything.